# Weblogic Transaction Behavior

Tags: transactions, ejb, weblogic

I'm working on an older EJB 2 application.
In the ejb-jar.xml, I see:

```
<container-transaction>
 <method><ejb-name><method-name>someMethod...
 <trans-attribute>Required</trans-attribute>
```

Does this mean that all calls in "someMethod()" are in a transaction?
I ask because I have a few db inserts in someMethod(), and when one of the subsequent inserts fail, the first insert is not rolled back, and I thought being in a transaction it necessarily would.

Is there another setting I need to adjust so Weblogic does the rollback on any insert exceptions?